# [ERROR]: Visual: [/turtlebot4_1/standard_dock] already exists

Tags: gazebo, ros2, turtlebot

I am using ROS2 humble on Ubuntu 22.04 with ignition gazebo and I am trying to insert 2 turtlebot4 to my simulation. When I add only 1, it works, but when I add 2, I get many errors saying:

```
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [/turtlebot4_1/standard_dock] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [/turtlebot4_2/turtlebot4] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [/turtlebot4_2/standard_dock] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [/turtlebot4_1/turtlebot4] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_2/turtlebot4::oakd_rgb_camera_frame::rgbd_camera] for entity [78]. Parent not found with ID[77].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_1/turtlebot4::oakd_rgb_camera_frame::rgbd_camera] for entity [212]. Parent not found with ID[211].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_1/standard_dock::green_buoy_link::green_buoy] for entity [9]. Parent not found with ID[8].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_1/standard_dock::halo_link::halo] for entity [11]. Parent not found with ID[10].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_1/standard_dock::red_buoy_link::red_buoy] for entity [13]. Parent not found with ID[12].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_1/standard_dock::yellow_buoy_link::yellow_buoy] for entity [15]. Parent not found with ID[14].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_2/turtlebot4::base_link::cliff_front_left] for entity [26]. Parent not found with ID[21].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_2/turtlebot4::base_link::cliff_front_right] for entity [27]. Parent not found with ID[21].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_2/turtlebot4::base_link::cliff_side_left] for entity [28]. Parent not found with ID[21].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_2/turtlebot4::base_link::cliff_side_right] for entity [29]. Parent not found with ID[21].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_2/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_front_center_left::ir_intensity_front_center_left] for entity [48]. Parent not found with ID[47].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_2/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_front_center_right::ir_intensity_front_center_right] for entity [50]. Parent not found with ID[49].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_2/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_front_left::ir_intensity_front_left] for entity [52]. Parent not found with ID[51].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_2/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_front_right::ir_intensity_front_right] for entity [54]. Parent not found with ID[53].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_2/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_left::ir_intensity_left] for entity [56]. Parent not found with ID[55].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_2/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_right::ir_intensity_right] for entity [58]. Parent not found with ID[57].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_2/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_side_left::ir_intensity_side_left] for entity [60]. Parent not found with ID[59].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_2/turtlebot4::rplidar_link::rplidar] for entity [91]. Parent not found with ID[88].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_2/standard_dock::green_buoy_link::green_buoy] for entity [143]. Parent not found with ID[142].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_2/standard_dock::halo_link::halo] for entity [145]. Parent not found with ID[144].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_2/standard_dock::red_buoy_link::red_buoy] for entity [147]. Parent not found with ID[146].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_2/standard_dock::yellow_buoy_link::yellow_buoy] for entity [149]. Parent not found with ID[148].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_1/turtlebot4::base_link::cliff_front_left] for entity [160]. Parent not found with ID[155].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_1/turtlebot4::base_link::cliff_front_right] for entity [161]. Parent not found with ID[155].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_1/turtlebot4::base_link::cliff_side_left] for entity [162]. Parent not found with ID[155].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_1/turtlebot4::base_link::cliff_side_right] for entity [163]. Parent not found with ID[155].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_1/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_front_center_left::ir_intensity_front_center_left] for entity [182]. Parent not found with ID[181].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_1/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_front_center_right::ir_intensity_front_center_right] for entity [184]. Parent not found with ID[183].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_1/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_front_left::ir_intensity_front_left] for entity [186]. Parent not found with ID[185].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_1/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_front_right::ir_intensity_front_right] for entity [188]. Parent not found with ID[187].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_1/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_left::ir_intensity_left] for entity [190]. Parent not found with ID[189].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_1/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_right::ir_intensity_right] for entity [192]. Parent not found with ID[191].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_1/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_side_left::ir_intensity_side_left] for entity [194]. Parent not found with ID[193].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/turtlebot4_1/turtlebot4::rplidar_link::rplidar] for entity [225]. Parent not found with ID[222].
```

and here is my launch file:

````
# OS lib for getting paths of files
import os

# helpful to the get the 'share' directory in which launch files are stored"
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from pathlib import Path

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, ExecuteProcess, SetEnvironmentVariable
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, PathJoinSubstitution

# create configuration variables for turtlebots
turtlebot4_1 = {
    'x': '0.0',
    'y': '0.0',
    'z': '0.0',
    'yaw': '3.15',
    'namespace': '/turtlebot4_1',
}

turtlebot4_2 = {
    'x': '10.0',
    'y': '10.0',
    'z': '0.0',
    'yaw': '0.0',
    'namespace': '/turtlebot4_2',
}

# this function is called later by ros2 launch with same return type
def generate_launch_description():

    # ------------------------------------------------------ Directories ------------------------------------------------------ #
    # get the paths of the share directory of different packages we want to run.                                                #
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
    pkg_ros_ign_gazebo = get_package_share_directory('ros_ign_gazebo'); # get gazebo share directory through which we can run gazebo
    pkg_slam_robots = get_package_share_directory('slam_robots') # get the share directory of the current packate ('slam_robots')
    pkg_turtlebot4_ignition_bringup = get_package_share_directory('turtlebot4_ignition_bringup')
    pkg_turtlebot4_description = get_package_share_directory('turtlebot4_description')
    
    # ------------------------------------------------------ Paths ------------------------------------------------------ #
    # used to extract the paths of the share files of different packages, as if any package wanted to allow anyone to     #
    # run it or configure it, that shall be done via package launch files where every launch file can have paramters to   #
    # configure paramters of the package.                                                                                 #
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
    ign_gazebo_launch = PathJoinSubstitution([pkg_ros_ign_gazebo, 'launch', 'ign_gazebo.launch.py'])    # get the path of ignition gazebo launch file
    slam_robots_world = PathJoinSubstitution([pkg_slam_robots, 'worlds', 'world.sdf'])  # get the path of the world.sdf to run the robot on it
    slam_robots_turtlebots_launch = PathJoinSubstitution([pkg_slam_robots, 'launch', 'slam_robots_turtlebots.launch.py'])    # get the path of another launch file in same project that's responsible for bringing up turtlebots to life 
    robot_spawn_launch = PathJoinSubstitution([pkg_turtlebot4_ignition_bringup, 'launch', 'turtlebot4_spawn.launch.py'])
    pkg_irobot_create_description = get_package_share_directory('irobot_create_description')


    # ------------------------------------------------------ actions ------------------------------------------------------ #
    # used to run the launch files of different packages given the paramters to those packages.                             #
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

    # set IGN_GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH environment variable to the parent folder of our model. so that gazebo can see all the include in the world directories
    # param: cmd a list where the first item is the executable and the rest are arguments to the executable
    # param: cwd the directory in which to run the executable
    # os.environ['IGN_GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH'] = os.environ['HOME']+'/Github_repos/SLAM-mapping-Robots/workspace/install/slam_robots/share/slam_robots/worlds'
    
    # Set ignition resource path
    ign_resource_path = SetEnvironmentVariable(
        name='IGN_GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH',
        value=[
            os.path.join(pkg_slam_robots, 'worlds'), ':' +
            str(Path(pkg_turtlebot4_description).parent.resolve()), ':' +
            str(Path(pkg_irobot_create_description).parent.resolve())])

    # execute the command 'ign gazebo world.sdf'
    ignition_gazebo_command = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([ign_gazebo_launch]),
        launch_arguments=[
            ('ign_args', [slam_robots_world])
            ]
    )

    # execute the launch file called 'slam_robots_turtlebots.launch.py' that's in the same project
    # spawn_turtlebot4_1_command = IncludeLaunchDescription(
    #     PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([slam_robots_turtlebots_launch]),
    #     launch_arguments=[
    #         ('namespace', turtlebot4_1['namespace']),
    #         ('rviz', 'false'),
    #         ('use_sim_time', 'true'),
    #         ('model', 'standard'),
    #         ('localization', 'false'),
    #         ('slam', 'false'),
    #         ('nav2', 'false'),
    #         ('x', turtlebot4_1['x']),
    #         ('y', turtlebot4_1['y']),
    #         ('z', turtlebot4_1['z']),
    #         ('yaw', turtlebot4_1['yaw']),
    #         ]
    # )
    # spawn_turtlebot4_2_command = IncludeLaunchDescription(
    #     PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([slam_robots_turtlebots_launch]),
    #     launch_arguments=[
    #         ('namespace', 'turtlebot2'),
    #         ('rviz', 'false'),
    #         ('use_sim_time', 'true'),
    #         ('model', 'standard'),
    #         ('localization', 'false'),
    #         ('slam', 'false'),
    #         ('nav2', 'false'),
    #         ('x', '1.0'),
    #         ('y', '0.0'),
    #         ('z', '0.0'),
    #         ('yaw', '0'),
    #         ]
    # )
    # execute the launch file called 'turtlebot4_spawn.launch.py' that's in turtlebot4 package which is responsible for spawning one turtlebot4
    robot1_spawn = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([robot_spawn_launch]),
        launch_arguments=[
            ('namespace', turtlebot4_1['namespace']),
            ('rviz', 'false'),
            # ('use_sim_time', 'true'),
            # ('model', 'standard'),
            # ('localization', 'false'),
            # ('slam', 'false'),
            # ('nav2', 'false'),
            ('x', turtlebot4_1['x']),
            ('y', turtlebot4_1['y']),
            ('z', turtlebot4_1['z']),
            ('yaw', turtlebot4_1['yaw']),
            ]
    )

    robot2_spawn = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([robot_spawn_launch]),
        launch_arguments=[
            ('namespace', turtlebot4_2['namespace']),
            ('rviz', 'false'),
            # ('use_sim_time', 'true'),
            # ('model', 'standard'),
            # ('localization', 'false'),
            # ('slam', 'false'),
            # ('nav2', 'false'),
            ('x', turtlebot4_2['x']),
            ('y', turtlebot4_2['y']),
            ('z', turtlebot4_2['z']),
            ('yaw', turtlebot4_2['yaw']),
            ]
    )

    # Clock bridge
    clock_bridge = Node(package='ros_gz_bridge', executable='parameter_bridge',
                        name='clock_bridge',
                        output='screen',
                        arguments=[
                            '/clock' + '@rosgraph_msgs/msg/Clock' + '[ignition.msgs.Clock'
                        ])
    




    # Create launch description and add actions
    ld = LaunchDescription([])
    ld.add_action(ign_resource_path)
    ld.add_action(ignition_gazebo_command)
    ld.add_action(clock_bridge)

    ld.add_action(robot2_spawn)
    ld.add_action(robot1_spawn)
    # ld.add_action(spawn_turtlebot4_1_command)
    # ld.add_action(spawn_turtlebot4_2_command)
    return ld 
```
````

Comment: For debugging: if you remove all code related to the robot 1 and leave only the robot 2, is there any gz topic or ros topic that have the 'turtlebot4_1' namespace?

Comment: @JoseLuisRivero, actually you are right, for some reason I don't see any topic created that's related to the spawn turtlebot but when I run the launch file from the turtlebot4 package, I can see the topics created. I even copied the same launch file from turtlebot4 pakcage and paste it in my package and replaced all launch configurations with my own configuration then tried to run it but no topic was created also. I don't know why this is happening and how to solve it.

Comment: @JoseLuisRivero, I managed to solve this problem and it was because the way I used to run the project. Anyway, now when I run the same file, the topics related to the 2 robots are created but Gazebo simulation give me black screen and I see in the logs this message keep repeating:
```[robot2.spawner_diffdrive_controller]: Waiting for '/robot2/controller_manager' node to exist```

Comment: Abdo, great to you managed to solved the problem. Could you please write an answer (not a comment) here describing how you solved it?. With respect to the black screen, we can follow it here https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/105496/multi-turtlebot4-causes-the-simulation-to-crash-in-gazebo-ignition right?