# multi-turtlebot4 causes the simulation to crash in gazebo ignition

Tags: gazebo, ros2, turtlebot

I am trying to simulate multiple turtlebot4 on Gazebo Fortress using ROS2 humble on my Ubuntu 22.04 but when I tried to run these commands, each in alone terminal:

```
ros2 launch turtlebot4_ignition_bringup turtlebot4_ignition.launch.py namespace:=salem
ros2 launch turtlebot4_ignition_bringup turtlebot4_spawn.launch.py namespace:=/robot2 x:=1.0 y:=0.0
ros2 launch turtlebot4_ignition_bringup turtlebot4_spawn.launch.py namespace:=/robot3 x:=2.0 y:=0.0
```

the simulation crashes and I get the following logs:

```
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [ground_plane] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [warehouse] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [pallet_box_0] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [shelf_big_0] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [shelf_big_1] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [shelf_big_2] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [shelf_3] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [shelf_4] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [shelf_5] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [shelf_6] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [shelf_7] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [shelf_big_3] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [shelf_big_4] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [shelf_0] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [shelf_1] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [shelf_2] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [barrier_0] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [barrier_1] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [barrier_2] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [barrier_3] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [chair_0] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [chair_1] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [fchair_0] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [fchair1] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [table0] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [Person 0 - Sitting] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:187] Parent entity with Id: [137] not found. Not adding model visual with ID[141]  and name [artifact_proximity_detector] to the rendering scene.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [Person 1 - Standing] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [Person 2 - Walking] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [salem/standard_dock] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [salem/turtlebot4] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [/robot2/standard_dock] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:201] Visual: [/robot2/turtlebot4] already exists
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[salem/turtlebot4::oakd_rgb_camera_frame::rgbd_camera] for entity [224]. Parent not found with ID[223].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/robot2/turtlebot4::oakd_rgb_camera_frame::rgbd_camera] for entity [358]. Parent not found with ID[357].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[salem/standard_dock::green_buoy_link::green_buoy] for entity [155]. Parent not found with ID[154].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[salem/standard_dock::halo_link::halo] for entity [157]. Parent not found with ID[156].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[salem/standard_dock::red_buoy_link::red_buoy] for entity [159]. Parent not found with ID[158].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[salem/standard_dock::yellow_buoy_link::yellow_buoy] for entity [161]. Parent not found with ID[160].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[salem/turtlebot4::base_link::cliff_front_left] for entity [172]. Parent not found with ID[167].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[salem/turtlebot4::base_link::cliff_front_right] for entity [173]. Parent not found with ID[167].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[salem/turtlebot4::base_link::cliff_side_left] for entity [174]. Parent not found with ID[167].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[salem/turtlebot4::base_link::cliff_side_right] for entity [175]. Parent not found with ID[167].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[salem/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_front_center_left::ir_intensity_front_center_left] for entity [194]. Parent not found with ID[193].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[salem/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_front_center_right::ir_intensity_front_center_right] for entity [196]. Parent not found with ID[195].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[salem/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_front_left::ir_intensity_front_left] for entity [198]. Parent not found with ID[197].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[salem/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_front_right::ir_intensity_front_right] for entity [200]. Parent not found with ID[199].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[salem/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_left::ir_intensity_left] for entity [202]. Parent not found with ID[201].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[salem/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_right::ir_intensity_right] for entity [204]. Parent not found with ID[203].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[salem/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_side_left::ir_intensity_side_left] for entity [206]. Parent not found with ID[205].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[salem/turtlebot4::rplidar_link::rplidar] for entity [237]. Parent not found with ID[234].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/robot2/standard_dock::green_buoy_link::green_buoy] for entity [289]. Parent not found with ID[288].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/robot2/standard_dock::halo_link::halo] for entity [291]. Parent not found with ID[290].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/robot2/standard_dock::red_buoy_link::red_buoy] for entity [293]. Parent not found with ID[292].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/robot2/standard_dock::yellow_buoy_link::yellow_buoy] for entity [295]. Parent not found with ID[294].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/robot2/turtlebot4::base_link::cliff_front_left] for entity [306]. Parent not found with ID[301].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/robot2/turtlebot4::base_link::cliff_front_right] for entity [307]. Parent not found with ID[301].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/robot2/turtlebot4::base_link::cliff_side_left] for entity [308]. Parent not found with ID[301].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/robot2/turtlebot4::base_link::cliff_side_right] for entity [309]. Parent not found with ID[301].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/robot2/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_front_center_left::ir_intensity_front_center_left] for entity [328]. Parent not found with ID[327].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/robot2/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_front_center_right::ir_intensity_front_center_right] for entity [330]. Parent not found with ID[329].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/robot2/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_front_left::ir_intensity_front_left] for entity [332]. Parent not found with ID[331].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/robot2/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_front_right::ir_intensity_front_right] for entity [334]. Parent not found with ID[333].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/robot2/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_left::ir_intensity_left] for entity [336]. Parent not found with ID[335].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/robot2/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_right::ir_intensity_right] for entity [338]. Parent not found with ID[337].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/robot2/turtlebot4::ir_intensity_side_left::ir_intensity_side_left] for entity [340]. Parent not found with ID[339].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [RenderUtil.cc:1277] Failed to create sensor with name[/robot2/turtlebot4::rplidar_link::rplidar] for entity [371]. Parent not found with ID[368].
```